# Android OnTouch listener on disabled EditText Field

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have two editText fields in my application and I want only one of them to be enabled at a time.  When edittext 1 is enabled - edittext 2 should be disabled, when edittext 2 is enabled edittext1 should be disabled.

When the user touches the disabled edittext field - it should be enabled and the second edittext field should be disabled.

What I created is code that uses an OnTouch listener but it doesn't work when the edittext field is disabled.  It doesn't change a disabled edittext field into an enabled edittext field.

What should be changed to make it work when touching the disabled field?

Code:

```
edittext1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
      if (edittext1.isEnabled()) 
      {
         edittext2.setEnabled(false);
         edittext1.setEnabled(true);
      }
      else
      {
         edittex2.setEnabled(false);
         edittext1.setEnabled(true);
      }
      return false;
   }
});

edittext2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){   

      if (edittext2.isEnabled()) 
      {
         edittex2.setEnabled(true);
         edittext1.setEnabled(false);
      }
      else
      {
          edittext2.setEnabled(true);
       edittext1.setEnabled(false);
      }
      return false;
   }
});
```

I've also tried to return true but it does't work either.

Comment: Did you try visibility change ?

Comment: you must override onTouch method

Comment: This is not possible...
If you disabled second edit text then you can't touch it..

Comment: You should change your logic...
like after complete first edit text its gone disabled and etc...